# Java Mocking method calls with Date as parameters

Tags: java, mockito

I have a repository method where I fetch transactions between some two dates. I want to mock this method but even though I set the same date in my real function call, and mock function call, when mockito compares these dates it results in false and the mock method is not called.

Here is my test code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,00);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
Date test = cal.getTime();
Date start = cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
Date end = cal.getTime();
Mockito.when(transactionRepository.findAllByDateBetween(start,end, PageRequest.of(1,5))).thenReturn(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Transaction(1l, new Date(), new BigDecimal(10), "USD", new BigDecimal(80), "TRY"),
                        new Transaction(2l, new Date(), new BigDecimal(10), "GBP", new BigDecimal(100), "TRY")
                ));
```

and here is my service code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(transactionDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,00);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
Date start = cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
Date end = cal.getTime();
return transactionRepository.findAllByDateBetween(start,end, PageRequest.of(page,pageSize)).stream().map(t -> t.toDto()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I mock this repository method and make it return a desired value when it is called with specific date?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> List.of(
        new Transaction(1L, new Date(), new BigDecimal(10), "USD", new BigDecimal(80), "TRY"),
        new Transaction(2L, new Date(), new BigDecimal(10), "GBP", new BigDecimal(100), "TRY")
)).when(transactionRepository).findAllByDateBetween(any(),any(), any());
```